# in_array multiple needles in strict mode

Tags: php

Already have function that checks if all elements of haystack == $needle

```
function in_array_all($needle, $haystack) {
   return (count(array_unique($haystack))==1 && $haystack[0]==$needle);
}
```

EX:

```
in_array_all(2, array(1,2,2,4)) //false
in_array_all(2, array(2,2,2,2)) //true
```

Need a similar function but that will accept multiple needles. Something like:

```
in_array_all_m(array(1,2), array(1,2,2,4)) //false
in_array_all_m(array(1,2,3), array(1,2)) //false
in_array_all_m(array(1,2), array(1,2,2,1)) //true
```

I know foreach always will work, but need an elegant solution.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? Stack Overflow is not here to write code for you. We are just here to help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function you_need_a_better_function_name($needles,$haystack) {
    return !array_diff($haystack,$needles);
}
```

So for example given `array(1,2)` and `array(1,2,2,4)`, `array_diff` will return `array(4)`, which is truthy, therefore the function returns false.

Likewise, for `array(1,2)` and `array(1,2,2,1)`, `array_diff` returns `array()`, which is falsy, and therefore the function returns true.

EDIT: Full correction:

```
function lets_try_that_again($needles,$haystack) {
    $unique_haystack = array_unique($haystack);
    $unique_needles = array_unique($needles);
    sort($unique_haystack);
    sort($unique_needles);
    return $unique_haystack == $unique_needles;
}
```

This will ensure that all needles are used at least once.

Comment: thanks, but if $needles=array(1,2,3); $haystack=array(1,2); your func will return true, should be false.

Comment: 10x again! if $needles=array(1,2); $haystack=array(1,2,3); => true... I am expecting false.

Comment: Arg, I'll get it right eventually, mark my words! Just give me a few minutes to look at the docs...

Comment: it looks like it's ok :) I thought I can get the result with a single line (like with array_diff) to avoid foreaching.. but thank you for your time!

Comment: added array_values if having strings as array values. you can paste it into your answer. function in_array_all_m($needles, $haystack) { sort($haystack); sort($needles); return array_values(array_unique($haystack))==array_values(array_unique($needles));
}

Comment: My code does `array_unique` first, because `sort` will automatically reassign array keys.